Excel: Multiple Conditional Formatting Based on the Value of Another Cell/Column?
Problem
I am trying to develop some very simple logic that says if column H2 and below is RED then color column J2 and below RED. This will apply also when I try to format the values to yellow or green.
What I have done so far

Conditional formatting
New rule
Use a formula to determine which cells to format
Develop logic: =$H2="GREEN", =$H2="YELLOW", =$H2="RED"

This has somewhat  worked but the issue is that the logic breaks for some reason I don't understand, see image below:
The last cell in the RED window turns to the next color and I don't understand why.
More below is a screenshot of my rules and my logic seems sound, does it have to do with "Rule (applied in order shown)"
image 1

image 2

image 3


You use $H2 (note the row is 2) in your rule but it applies to a range that starts on row 1, hence why the 1-row offset.

but row 1 is just the title of the column

Then why do you make it so "Applies to" covers the first row?

It's different because for some reason the logic I implemented incorrectly colored a "RED" column to yellow as you see in image 2

@Jaskeil in case it wasn't clear, if you apply a conditional format to the whole column, your formula must start at 1 in order to keep the result in sync. Doesn't matter that row 1 is the title, assuming that the title isn't one of the three colors.

that did the trick, thank you
